# What is the use case for Merge function SQL Clr?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sqlclr

I am writing a CLR userdefinedAggregate function to implement median. While I understand all the other function which I have to implement. I can not understand, what is the use of the merge function.

I am getting a vague idea that if aggregated function is partially evaluated ( i.e. evaluated for some rows with one group and the remaining in other ) then the values needs to be aggregated. If its the case is there a way to test this ?

Please let me know if any of the above is not clear or if you need any further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your vague idea is correct.
From [Requirements for CLR User-Defined Aggregates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131051.aspx)

> This method can be used to merge another instance of this aggregate
>   class with the current instance. The query processor uses this method
>   to merge multiple partial computations of an aggregation.

The parameter to merge is another instance of your aggregate and you should merge the aggregated data in that instance to your current instance.
You can have a look at the sample [string concatenate aggregate](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131056.aspx). The merge method add the concatenated strings from the parameter to the current instance of the aggregate class.